# Capturing output of data and include date and time to a CSV file using Powershell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to capture the command output to a CSV file using export-csv -append and adding date command output to the same file using out-file. I want to use the same csv file and run the command/script for every hour and appending the date command output. I understood that because that get-date output column data differs from the original get-service columns its throwing error. Is there any way to achieve this functionality. This mainly for reporting the service every hour in CSV file

Example:file1.csv

```
07/07/2020
Status   Name               DisplayName
------   ----               -----------
Stopped  AarSvc_3e53ef98    Agent Activation Runtime_3e53ef98
Running  AdobeARMservice    Adobe Acrobat Update Service
Running  AdobeUpdateService AdobeUpdateService
Running  AGMService         Adobe Genuine Monitor Service

07/07/2020 
Status   Name               DisplayName
------   ----               -----------
Stopped  AarSvc_3e53ef98    Agent Activation Runtime_3e53ef98
Running  AdobeARMservice    Adobe Acrobat Update Service
Running  AdobeUpdateService AdobeUpdateService
Running  AGMService         Adobe Genuine Monitor Service
```

Error:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Get-Service | export-csv -Append -path  'D:\laptop backup\test.csv'
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> get-date

Friday, July 10, 2020 5:10:37 PM


PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> get-date  | out-file -Append -path 'D:\laptop backup\test.csv'
Out-File : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'path'.
At line:1 char:30
+ get-date  | out-file -Append -path 'D:\laptop backup\test.csv'
+                              ~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Out-File], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.OutFileCommand
```

Comment: For `Out-File`, the parameter is `-FilePath` not `-Path`.

Comment: @AdminOfThings, `-Path` is an alias of `-FilePath` in the context of `Out-File` (and, regrettably, both forms interpret the argument as a _wildcard expression_; use `-LiteralPath` to ensure verbatim use).

Comment: @mklement0, For whatever reason, `-Path` does not work for me. `-LiteralPath` does, however.

Comment: Thanks for following up, @AdminOfThings: I forgot that alias `-Path` for `-FilePath` is available in PS [Core] v6+ only.

Answer (score 1):

Often, the best way to add a property which isn't already present is to use the `Select-Object` command with a calculated property:

```
# Specify the full path to the CSV file
$CsvFile = '...'

# Get a string representation of the current date and time in whatever format is useful
$CaptureDateTime = Get-Date -Format 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff'

# Get the services, add the date and time property, and append it to the CSV file
Get-Service |
    Select-Object -Property Status, Name, DisplayName, @{n='CaptureDateTime';e={$CaptureDateTime}} |
    Export-Csv $CsvFile -NoTypeInformation -Append
```